# Why in some PCs you need to disable front panel audio jack detection to make it work?

Tags: windows-10, audio, desktop-computer

I want to ask why front panel audio jack of my windows 10 pc *(with realtek HD audio)* cannot detect audio devices plugged in it, without disabling it?

Yes, it is true that it works when I disable front panel detection, but why it does not work normally without disabling the detection? Why my PC case is not able to detect audio devices automatically?

Why do I need to disable front panel audio detection to enable the devices plugged in it?

**I have researched a lot on google about this but cannot find right information. I would be thankful to you all if I got required knowledge.**

*I know this is not a very big issues, But it becomes kind of annoying sometimes that,  why my PC is not able to detect audio devices plugged into front panel until I disable front panel detection. And also because I am PC enthusiast but do not have knowledge related to this issue.*

Comment: Because it is windows 10 and full of things that do not work properly

Comment: @Moab, Oh that means it is windows problem and not hardware's problem? Okay. Maybe they should think to bring another windows like 11 or 12 without this issues.

Comment: @Moab, any other OS that you would recommend that is better in everything and user friendly also?